# Asset pipeline not generating sass image-urls properly - missing asset path

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I'm on the way to upgrade my application from Rails 3.0 to 3.1.3 (before I upgraded from 2.3). Now I want to enable the asset pipeline.

I've moved my stylesheets over and have now my manifest file looks like this

#### app.scss

```
@import "base";
```

#### _base.scss

```
.drawTrack {
    background-image: image-url('buttons/edit-20.png') !important;
}
```

the resulting css however is missing the 'asset' path

#### app.css

```
.drawTrack {
  background-image: url('/buttons/edit-20.png') !important; 
}
```

in my Gemfile I have

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sprockets'
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'compass-rails'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
```

#### application.rb

```
config.assets.enabled = true
# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
config.assets.version = '1.0'

# Precompile *all* assets, except those that start with underscore
config.assets.precompile << /(^[^_\/]|\/[^_])[^\/]*$/
config.prefix = 'assets'
```

#### development.rb

```
# Do not compress assets
config.assets.compress = false
# Expands the lines which load the assets
config.assets.debug = true
```

previously I used jammit, but I removed the gem now.

might be related. 
requesting /assets/index.js returns me the proper javascript file, however the generated path /assets/index.js?body=1 returns me a blank javascript.

thx

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself
had to update application.rb and have the bundler line replaced with

```rb
# If you have a Gemfile, require the gems listed there, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require *Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end
```